# iOS Swift Casting JSON response with strange format to dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm attempting to cast a JSON response in swift to a useable dictionary. This seemed like a simple task, however the JSON response I am getting is formatted strangely, and no matter what I try, I am unable to cast it to a dictionary. All of the google examples I've been able to find assume that the format of the JSON response will be as follows:

```
    {
    "someKey": 42.0,
    "anotherKey": {
        "someNestedKey": true
    },
    {
    "someKey": 42.0,
    "anotherKey": {
        "someNestedKey": true
    }
```

However, the print response in swift I'm receiving using the code below is formatted as follows:

```
{assets = (
    {
    "someKey": 42.0,
    "anotherKey": {
        "someNestedKey": true
    },
    {
    "someKey": 42.0,
    "anotherKey": {
        "someNestedKey": true
    }
);
}
```

Here is as far as I was able to get in attempting to cast this data to a dictionary in swift. It adds "assets" as the single key in the dictionary, with the value of that key being the entire rest of the response.

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://\(apiKey):\(password)@\(yourStore).myshopify.com/admin/themes/\(currentThemeID)/assets.json")!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        if let urlContent = data {
            do {

                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: [.allowFragments, JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers])
                print(jsonResult)
                if let dictionary = jsonResult as? [String: [String]] {
                    print(dictionary)
                }

            } catch {
                print("json processing failed")
            }
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

I'm pretty sure the hang up resides around the presence of the two "parenthesis" and "semi-colon" in the JSON response. I'm unable to find any documentation on how those characters effect the response, or on how to handle them when attempting to down-cast in swift.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
I've pulled up the JSON response in my browser, and here is the formatting:

```
{"assets":[{"key":"assets\/1-1.png","public_url":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0810\/2125\/t\/22\/assets\/1-1.png?5272098227851596200","created_at":"2016-05-16T16:58:27-05:00","updated_at":"2016-05-16T16:58:27-05:00","content_type":"image\/png","size":9127,"theme_id":124078279}{"key":"templates\/search.liquid","public_url":null,"created_at":"2016-05-16T16:59:04-05:00","updated_at":"2016-05-16T16:59:04-05:00","content_type":"text\/x-liquid","size":2931,"theme_id":124078279}]}
```

This JSON response does not have the assets = (); portion in it, and is formatted correctly. Somehow my swift code is improperly parsing the data?

Comment: Is that response the result of `print(jsonResult)` or the actual response data you are getting?  It isn't valid json

Comment: @dan I pulled the response up in my browser, and it is formatted correctly in there. I posted the snippit in the question edit above. This tells me the issue resides in my Swift code, and how it's parsing the data?

Comment: To answer your question @dan, it is the result of the print in swift, not the actual json response.

Comment: You should be casting it as `[String: [[String: Any]]]`

Comment: That was it @dan. Thanks for your time. If you add as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeatedly cast as [String: Any] to get down to the part of the JSON response you want.

```
    do {
        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: [.allowFragments, JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers])
        print(jsonResult)
        guard
            let dictionary = jsonResult as? [String: Any],
            let assetData = dictionary["assets"] as? [String: Any] else {
                print("The JSON structure doesn't meet our expectations \(urlContent)")
                return
        }
        print(assetData)
    } catch {
        print("json processing failed")
    }
```